# ¿Está bien responder una pregunta que ya ha sido respondida correctamente pero sin una buena explicación?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, convenciones-sociales

Hoy me encontré una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235348/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-cambiar-el-color-de-los-li-en-bootstrap-no-funciona-impor) la cual fue respondida correctamente pero la respuesta carecía de una explicación, solo decía en código lo que había que hacer para la solución del problema propuesto.

Pensé en responder con una explicación más amplia pero decidí no hacerlo y preferí colgar esta pregunta acá para saber cómo proceder si vuelve a ocurrir lo mismo.

Comment: En mi opinión si. Yo probablemente intentaría primero hacer un comentario al autor de la respuesta indicándole que tratara de mejorarla, pero también me parece totalmente aceptable añadir una respuesta con una mejor explicación. Al final, el objetivo del sitio es tener un catálogo de respuestas **de calidad**, asi que si crees que puedes mejorar la calidad de una respuesta existente, bienvenido.

Comment: En mi opinión, concuerdo con @Pikoh. Es mas, muchas veces lo hice. Paso uno, comentar la respuesta existente solicitando que añada mas información para mejorar la calidad de la respuesta y en caso de ser necesario guiarlo a "como responder". Luego si ves que no mejora la respuesta y crees poder  mejorarla, puedes crear tu propia respuesta y te aseguro que sera muy bien vista por la comunidad siempre y cuando sea una respuesta de calidad obviamente. Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Es correcto**, se trata de mejorar la información con la cual contribuimos al sitio. En ocasiones los usuarios nuevos dan como aceptada una respuesta que no tiene una buena explicación pero esto no debe impedirte a agregar una respuesta más completa y de mejor calidad.

Si revisas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

> **Asegurarte de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a
>   esto. Y si no, provee una alternativa viable.** La respuesta puede ser
>   “no hagas eso” pero debe también incluir “trata esto en vez”.
>   Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección
>   correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o
>   simplificaciones en tu respuesta. **La brevedad es aceptable pero
>   respuestas robustas son las mejores.**

Si la respuesta actual consideras que solo tiene un pequeño detalle o un error, puedes comentarlo al miembro de la comunidad ya que puede ser que se le haya escapado un detalle o incluso sugerir explicar el código (algo que veo realizaste), recordemos las respuestas que son solo código y no llevan explicación se consideran de baja calidad.

Pero aunque se tenga una respuesta probablemente puedes responder con otra respuesta que tenga otra alternativa para resolver el problema o incluso realizar una explicación más amplia del problema.